# Change position of UISearchController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a UITableView which has UISearchController (added programmatically). SearchController is added to header of TableView.(screenshot 2). However, I want to have a search view first in the middle of screen when app opens and after user starts to search, TableView appears and start to show datas.(screenshot 1)

I try to add UISearchBar inside Storyboard and connect it to UISearchController but can't assign it directly.

[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Screenshot 1]

```
let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Setup the Search Controller
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true
    mTableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar }
```

Answer (score 0):

1# You can work around this point by change tableview size and position at start by tableview to middle of screen as you want , after user start search you can change frame to View Boundary

2#  Better => you can use UItextField to create your own search Controler  and custamize as wanted

Comment: I tried first one but I want TableView not to show and when I do TableView hidden, searchbar also hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by creating a UIView inside storyboard and add searchcontroller inside the view.

1. Create a UIView in Storyboard
2. Add IBOutlet
3. Add SearchController as a subview of UIView.